Агент для сбора и отправки данных с БД Firebird. какое условие прописать для выборки из таблицы данных?
Здравствуйте есть Агент для сбора и отправки данных с БД Firebird . Заполнил файл конфигурации objectSettings.json но не могу понять какое условие прописать для выборки из таблицы данных.
  "TankTransferParams": {
        "StartTime": "DT_BEGIN",
        "EndTime": "DT_FINAL",
        "MassStart": "MASS_BEGIN",
        "MassFinish": "MASS_END",
        "LevelStart": "LEVEL_BEGIN",
        "LevelFinish": "LEVEL_END",
        "VolumeStart": "VOLUME_BEGIN",
        "VolumeFinish": "VOLUME_END"
         
      }
    //"TransferCondition": "Условие выборки из таблицы данных трансферов, значение string",
     // "MeasurementCondition": "Условие выборки из таблицы данных резервуаров, значение string"
    },

в проекте используется код
  private static string getFireBirdTransferQuery(string queryParams, string timeStampParam, string tableName, ObjectSource source, int ps, DateTime lastSyncDate, Logger logger)
    {
        var lastSyncDateQuery = $"{source.TransferCondition} and {timeStampParam} > '{lastSyncDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")}' order by {timeStampParam} asc";
        var query = $"SELECT FIRST {ps} {queryParams} FROM {tableName} {lastSyncDateQuery}";
        //logger.Debug($"Query - {query}");
        return query;
    }

если делаю вот такой SQL запрос к бд
SELECT FIRST 1000
    DT_BEGIN, DT_FINAL, MASS_BEGIN, MASS_END, LEVEL_BEGIN, LEVEL_END, VOLUME_BEGIN, VOLUME_END
FROM DS_DATA
WHERE DT_BEGIN IS NOT NULL AND DT_FINAL IS NOT NULL AND DT_BEGIN > '2024-05-05 12:00:00.000'
ORDER BY DT_BEGIN ASC;


Данные формируются.
Если в строке прописываю "TransferCondition": "WHERE DT_BEGIN IS NOT NULL AND DT_FINAL IS NOT NULL AND DT_BEGIN > '2024-05-05 12:00:00.000'"
программ не запускается. Как нужно заполнить  не пойму.

А какой код попадает в логгер? именно тот, который потом выполняется без проблем в IBExpert? если так, то проблема не в тексте запроса. PS. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что в TransferCondition должно присутствовать WHERE...

TransferCondition пробывал с where и без программа не запускается. Если комментирую строку. запускается но  в логе ошибки

ERROR AMultiServerClient - Error while collecting data 1. Error: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 7, column 21

код который выполняется IBExpert. Я сам написал для проверки как его преобразовать и довить в строку для выполнения


Строка кода logger.Debug($"Query - {query}"); записывает сформированный текст запроса в лог. Покажите этот текст. 2. Запрос в IBExpert работает - положите этот текст в переменную query вместо сборки текста запроса кодом и проверьте, получаете ли результат.

